# How to get jws cache location in the client

Tags: java, linux, caching, java-native-interface, java-web-start

As we know, each JVM process would create a cache directory. Such like this:

```
/root/.java/deployment/cache/6.0/35

2df4eba3-16182299      2df4eba3-16182299-n    2df4eba3-4678facc.idx
2df4eba3-16182299.idx  2df4eba3-1a176e8d.idx  2df4eba3-654177dc.idx
```

2df4eba3-16182299-n is the cache location.

I want to get the JWS cache location like this using JNI programming. I tried to get the location using this way:

```
    DIR *dirp;
    FILE *fp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char path[2048];
    char link[2048];
    char read_buf[2048];
    dirp = opendir("/proc/self/fd");
    if (dirp == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    while((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        char *tmp = entry->d_name;
    int res = 0;
    sprintf(link, "/proc/self/fd/%s", entry->d_name);
    res = readlink(link, path, sizeof(path));

    if (res < 0 || res >= sizeof(path))
    {
        continue;
    }
    int j = 0;
    if (strstr(path, "libgoodluck.so") != NULL)
    {
        path[res] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    }
```

I load library libgoodluck.so, and this will be downloaded in the cache location. But I could not get the correct path.

How should I do to get the correct location?

Comment: If the native is added as a `nativelib` in the JNLP, it will already be on the run-time class-path.  No need to discover the cache location.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but how should I do to get the cache location? I looked up System.getProperty function can not get it.

Comment: *"..but how should I do to get the cache location?"*  You ***shouldn't.***  Sun (before Oracle bought them) decided the installation path of the app. was no business of the app.  They took explicit measures to ***prevent*** apps. from discovering that path.

Comment: I know that I can not get the location using java, that's why I was tring to use c language to get it.